# How to make ffmpeg delete the original file after changing containers? (using a send to bat file)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg, mp4, mkv

I'm currently using a bat file in my shell:sendto folder that allows me to right click MKV files and open a cmd window that uses ffmpeg to change containers and produces an mp4 in the same directory as the source file. It works great, but I'd like to automate the process of deleting the original MKVs after (successfully) changing containers, and skipping the recycle bin if possible.

Right now my .bat file is like follows:

```
"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i %1 -codec copy "%~n1.mp4"
```

I've looked it up already but could only find a similar question about batch processing an entire folder and without the sendto part, and I wasn't sure how to make that work for me. 
So if someone could point me towards what to append to it to make it happpen, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks ! :)

Comment: The first recommendation, I'll make is do not put a batch file in SendTo, just place a shortcut to it in there. I'd also change `%1` to `"%~1"`, but it's probably not necessary in this case, as I'd assume explorer will auto quote if necessary. As for your question, is simply appending `&& Del /A /F "%~1"` sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: That works! I can't mark that as the answer though so repost that as a reply? Is there an actual reason I shouldn't put the batch file itself in sendto, or is that just kinda frowned upon?

Comment: I wouldn't do it simply because, I want my files in my own locations, but if you take a look at what's already in there, you'll probably find that they're already shortcuts too. I'm not saying that it will not work, but I am certainly frowning at the thought. I would always offer the same advice for the StartUp location too.