# How to make ffmpeg delete original file after conversion?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to convert all .mp4 movies in a folder and delete the old one afterwards.

Does anyone have a hint? I've been trying for hours.

The only thing I found is:
[How to make ffmpeg delete the original file after changing containers? (using a send to bat file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661930/how-to-make-ffmpeg-delete-the-original-file-after-changing-containers-using-a)

my idea:

```
ffmpeg -i *.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac *.mp4
```

It asks if files can be overwritten, but then it doesn't:https://pastebin.com/tJtWpm2n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ffmpeg you can't directly write to the same file you're currently reading from, but one thing you can do instead is write to a temporary file, then replace the original if ffmpeg converted successfully.

```bash
for f in *.mp4; do
    ffmpeg -i "${f}" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac "tmp_${f}" && mv "tmp_${f}" "${f}"
done
```

So ffmpeg reads from variable `${f}` containing the original filename matched in the `*.mp4` pattern and writes to `tmp_${f}`, then `&&` tests ffmpeg exited successfully before replacing the original file with `mv`.

You might also want to ensure `"tmp_${f}"` does not exist first, which only takes a few more steps.

```bash
for f in *.mp4; do
    tmpf=$(mktemp -p ./ -t "tmp.XXXXXXXXXX.${f##*.}") # can now be extended for any file extension
    ffmpeg -i "${f}" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac "${tmpf}" && mv "${tmpf}" "${f}"
done
```

Comment: Wow, works like a charm!

How can I let this be done in all subfolders too?